# Installing cordova plugins

Tags: cordova

I am using **ionic** and **angularjs** for my cordova project. 
 Currently I am using **cordova version 4.0**. How Can I install Cordova plugins (for example camera plugin) **manually** instead of using CLI Command add plugin ?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You need the ionic command to add plugin

> ionic plugin add org.xxxx

Comment: If I get this right the question was how to add plugins **without** CLI.

Comment: Okay sorry, if you look the CLI command. The verbose write the review of files change. Two xml files are more important in each platform. What's your platform ?

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the plugin repo, read the plugin.xml file and move the files as describe in the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html). By the way, this is a bad way to do it, always use first the CLI